# Is this variable global in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following abridged code (in ES6):

```
for (let i = 0, labelsLength = this.predefinedLabels.length; i < labelsLength; i++) {
...
```

Is `labelsLength` being made into a global (`window`) variable?

Assuming this is the entire context you have.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if you can access the variable outside the loop?

Comment: Put `window.labelsLength` in your console and hit Enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a global variable.

[Mozilla Developer Network here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) states:

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable,
>   optionally initializing it to a value.

Syntax

```
   let var1 [= value1] [, var2 [= value2]] [, ..., varN[= valueN]];
```

As you can see multiple declarations seperated by commas is fully supported.